# Prompt in rock, paper, scissors code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm testing a javascript code using HTML. And for some reason it won't work.

Here's the [HTML source code](https://github.com/kakol20/Rock-Paper-Scissors/blob/master/Rock%20Paper%20Scissors.html) and here's the [Javascript source code](https://github.com/kakol20/Rock-Paper-Scissors/blob/master/RockPaperScissors.js)

**Snippet**

```js
function reload() {
  location.reload()
}

var choice = prompt("Do you pick rock, paper or scissors?");
var userChoice = choice.toLowerCase();
var computerChoice = Math.random();
var computerChoiceCapitalized = "None";

var capitalize = function(word) {
  return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
};

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
  if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "paper") {
      return "You lose!";
    };
    else if (choice2 === "scissors") {
      return "You win!";
    };
    else {
      return "It's a draw!";
    };
  };
  else if (choice1 === "paper") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
      return "You lose!";
    };
    else if (choice2 === "rock") {
      return "You win!";
    };
    else {
      return "It's a draw!";
    };
  };
  else {
    if (choice2 === "rock") {
      return "You lose!";
    };
    else if (choice2 === "paper") {
      return "You win!";
    };
    else {
      return "It's a draw!";
    };
  };
};

if (computerChoice <= 0.33) {
  computerChoice = "rock";
  computerChoiceCapitalized = capitalize(computerChoice);
};
else if (computer choice <= 0.66) {
  computerChoice = "paper";
  computerChoiceCapitalized = capitalize(computerChoice);
};
else {
  computerChoice = "scissors";
  computerChoiceCapitalized = capitalize(computerChoice);
};

if (userChoice === "rock") {
  document.write("Computer: " + computerChoiceCapitalized + ". ");
  document.write(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));
};
else if (userChoice === "paper") {
  document.write("Computer: " + computerChoiceCapitalized + ". ");
  document.write(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));
};
else if (userChoice === "scissors") {
  document.write("Computer: " + computerChoiceCapitalized + ". ");
  document.write(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));
};
else {
  document.write("You need to pick rock, paper or scissors! Press the Reload button")
};
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#000000" text="#339933" link="#33FF00" vlink="#666666" alink="#666600">
    <h1 align="center">
     <font face="Arial">
      Rock Paper Scissors
     </font>
    </h1>
  <p align="center">
    <font face="Arial">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=LF30CCzx"></script>
 </font>
  </p>
  <p align="center">
    <button onclick="reload()">
      Reload Page
    </button>
  </p>
  <p align="center">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/MJRmrns.gif" width="200">
  </p>
  <p align="center">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/the_banana_guy_" target="blank">
      <button>
        <font face="Arial">
            By kakol20
        </font>
      </button>
    </a>
  </p>
</body>
```

I'm just simply trying to make a Rock Paper Scissor game, and for some reason it won't work when ran along the HTML code.

Comment: Could you post your code here?

Comment: Also please be specific about how exactly it doesn't work (error messages, expected vs. actual behavior etc.).

Comment: Yes define "code won't work".

Comment: It comes out as nothing. The prompt function does not work. Basically everything doesn't work

Comment: On a side note, this code has tons of obsolete content. CSS is used to style pages nowadays, not attributes and font tags.

Comment: you used `;` after `if` blocks which has `else` blocks.
prompt accepts 2 inputs, do it `var choice = prompt("Do you pick rock", "paper or scissors?");`

Comment: The source code also happens to be stored on another domain which won't work due to XSS protections, and the script tag shouldn't be inside a paragraph. In other words, it's a mess. If you need to learn HTML and JS, I recommend looking at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn)

Comment: @JacqueGoupil XSS doesn't block scripts in a different domain. And script tags can be located almost anywhere.

Comment: @Barmar Right. My mistake. My browser just happens to block JS from other domains found inside iframes, so it might break the fiddle, but that's not XSS. Still, I wouldn't place a script tag 'anywhere' even if it works.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: Your code doesn't work because your javascript is *loaded* in your HTML page somewhere, but the code never *executes*. For two reasons: it has syntax errors, so the `prompt()` doesn't run. But main reason is that you need code somewhere to execute javascript functions.

Your javascript code has commands in it that assume you are not working in a HTML environment, but work in a console type environment.
(the `document.write()` statements suggest that)

A good place for you to start would be to go to [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/dawisutaxe/edit?js,console,output) where you can debug and run your plain javascript code.
You will probably need to fix typos (; etc).
And also learn that you need to encapsulate your code in **functions**.

Then move on to a place where you can learn how to let javascript and HTML work together. E.g. [this tutorial](http://javascript.info/tutorial/adding-script-html)

**If you want to peek at a working version with your code with fixes: [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wintvelt/3ou6b60j/4/)**
Changes I made to your code:

- changed the 'reload' button to 'reset game'= shortcut to fix unnecessary complete reload of page.
- removed the 'load javascript from external website' from your HTML
- added two `<p>` elements both with an `id=` tag, so you can access them from javascript
- changed the `document.write()` to a custom defined `updateHTMLWith()` function, which gets one of the `<p>` elements from the HTML code, and puts the text in the HTML
- changed the name of the `reload()` function to `RunGame()` and moved the 'make computer move, compare and display results part of your code in there'
- fixed typos: removed unnecessary ';' after the else statements
- changed a `computer choice` typo to `computerChoice` in one of the if statements.

Comment: Your version doesn't check for unacceptable answers...anything other than 'rock' or 'paper' or 'scissors' fails to produce a new result other than changing the text back to "Press the Run Game button". You have no reset button, as the OP requested. Great reading materials, though.

Comment: Fixed small typo in (otherwise working code) check for unacceptable answers + semantic update to text inside button. BTW: OP did not ask for reset button, but asked why his code did not work. I'll leave it to the OP to decide whether fixes to original code or completely different code are most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/csworen/onowjy4n/) for a non pop-out (window.alert) version of a solution to your problem, feel free to mark as correct or not. I will attempt to explain how it should go in the code below:

**HTML**

You should import your CSS in a `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">` statement in your `<head>` section (above the `<body>` tag).

For this code sample, the 3 buttons will give set your player's choice and fire the sequence that will display the results of the game. The `Try Again` button will reset the board and hide the computer's choice and results (since they will not have been determined yet). Also, it's typical to have your script tag at the bottom of your html page so the content loads faster.

```
<body onload="reload()">
   <h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
   <div>
      <hr>
      <p>Choose your method</p>
      <button type="button" onclick="rock()">Rock</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="paper()">Paper</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="scissors()">Scissors</button>
   </div>
   <div>
      <p id="computer">The computer chose: <span id="choice"></span></p>
      <p id="result"></p>
      <br id="noResult"/>
   </div>
   <div>
      <hr>
      <button type="button" onclick="reload()">Try Again</button>
      <p><i>You can also just make a new selection...</i></p>
   </div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
   <!-- <script src="js/script.js"></script> -->
</body>
```

**CSS**

This is just a restatement of your current content alterations with the addition of my custom footer (with `i` or italicized text), of which color and text can be adjusted to meet your needs.

```
h1, p, div, body {
   text-align: center;
   font-family: arial;
   background-color: #000;
   color: #339933;
}
div {
   width: 66%;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
i {
   font-size: 8pt;
}
#footer {
   font-family: papyrus;
   color: #008080;
}
```

**JavaScript**

This is where the magic happens for your application, obviously.

First you want to initialize some useful variables (globally) that aren't limited to the contents of functions. You can do more than this, but I decided to keep it simple. The reload function does the same as you intended, just resets the board and hides the results. The next 3 functions set the players' choice based on the button clicked. Choose is what selects the computer's choice, reveals the computer's choice, and calls to qualify. Qualify is your series of if-else-if/switch-case blocks that determine the winner based on the choices of player and computer. The footer function (called in reload) makes sure that your custom-styled footer is visible with the current year (for copyright purposes).

```
var choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
var player = '';
var computer = '';

function reload() {
   footer();
   document.getElementById('computer').style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById('result').style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById('noResult').style.display = 'block';
   player = '';
   computer = '';
}

function rock() {
   player = choices[0];
   computer = choose();
}

function paper() {
   player = choices[1];
   computer = choose();
}

function scissors() {
   player = choices[2];
   computer = choose();
}

function choose() {
   var choice = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 0) + 0);
   computer = choices[choice];
   document.getElementById('choice').innerHTML = computer + '.';
   document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = qualify();
   document.getElementById('computer').style.display = 'block';
   document.getElementById('result').style.display = 'block';
   document.getElementById('noResult').style.display = 'none';
}

function qualify() {
   var choice = '';
   switch (player) {
       case choices[0]:
           switch (computer) {
               case choices[1]:
                   choice = "Computer wins. Try again?";
                   break;
               case choices[2]:
                   choice = "You win! Play again?";
                   break;
           }
           break;
       case choices[1]:
           switch (computer) {
               case choices[0]:
                   choice = "You win! Play again?";
                   break;
               case choices[2]:
                   choice = "Computer wins. Try again?";
                   break;
           }
           break;
       case choices[2]:
           switch (computer) {
               case choices[0]:
                   choice = "Computer wins. Try again?";
                   break;
               case choices[1]:
                   choice = "You win! Play again?";
                   break;
           }
           break;
       default:
           choice = "Tie! Wasn't that fun?";
           break;
   }
   return choice;
}

function footer() {
   var d = new Date();
   var y = d.getFullYear();
   document.getElementById('footer').innerHTML = "&copy; " + y + " C&sect;";
}
```

I hope this has given you some insight into how you should structure your code, or at least solved your short-term goal of passing the assignment.

-C§